# How can I copy a file from the isolated storage to the Downloads folder?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, file-copying

I'm trying to copy my database file from the isolated storage to the Download folder (or any folder that the user can access).

Currently my database is stored in:

```
/data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/files/Databases/MyDatabase.db
```

I tried to use this code:

```
public string GetCustomFilePath(string folder, string filename)
{
    var docFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, folder);

    if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);

    return Path.Combine(libFolder, filename);
}


var bas = GetDatabaseFilePath("MyDatabase.db");
var des = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads, "MyDatabase.db");
File.Copy(bas, des);
```

The `Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads` property returns the path `Download`, which is the name of the downloads folder.
But `File.Copy()` throws an exception telling

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Destination directory not found:
>   Download.

I tried to use a slash before like this: `/Download/MyDatabase.db` with no luck.

Is there any way to copy a file like that? Do I need any permission?

Comment: you can't just write to the downloads folder.  You can use DownloadManager to save files to the Downloads folder

Comment: You need external storage permission to write to "Download", once you have that, you can use the `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` to obtain the path of the Download folder and use the standard .Net `File.Copy` api...

Answer (score 4):

1st) Yes, you do need permissions to write to external storage.

You can get the runtime time permission required by doing it yourself:

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/

Or via a 3rd-party plugin, such as James Montemagno's `PermissionsPlugin`

- https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

2nd) Once your user accepts that it is ok to write to external storage, you can use:

```
Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads
```

To obtain the path of the device's public Download folder, i.e. using a Forms' dependency service:

```
public interface IDownloadPath
{
    string Get(); 
}

public class DownloadPath_Android : IDownloadPath
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
    }
}
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

You end up with something like:

```
public void Handle_Button(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = "someFile.txt";
    using (var stream = File.Create(Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName)))
    {
       // just creating a dummy file to copy (in the cache dir using Xamarin.Essentials
    }


    var downloadPath = DependencyService.Get<IDownloadPath>().Get();
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fileName), downloadPath);
}
```

Comment: how about files inside "Assets" folder? i think what Nicke is trying to say is "/data/user/0/com.companyname.appname/files/Databases/MyDatabase.db"  can't be indentified.  dummy file is working fine because it's currently open. Opening for example a .pdf file then copying it into download directory, can you do that?