# Where folder and files are actually created with PCL Storage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using PCLStorage. When getting the local folder using

```
IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
```

it retrieves /data/data/com.company.MyApp/files, however, that path does not exist anywhere. I used

```
await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(VIDEO_FOLDER, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

to create a folder, and it is created because I check folder existence using CheckExistsAsync. But I cannot find it !! where is it?

I need to find it because I have to save a file in there using file explorer. The more similar folder I've found is \Internal storage\Android\data\com.company.MyApp\files, but the created folder does not appear there. Is this magical or something?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: It is a folder in your app's private sandbox, unless you are using a rooted device or an unlock emulator image you can not access it from outside of the app.

Comment: @SushiHangover this is a physical device. Is there a way to use a public folder? I need to save an MP4 file there so it is ideal to be able to browse the device file system from my PC windows explorer connected to the device using USB connection. If it is not possible, how can save the file there?

Comment: You can save or copy it to one of the public folders: see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875215/in-xamarin-forms-how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-the-isolated-storage-to-the-downloa/56877225#56877225

Comment: @SushiHangover I read that I can access External storage, but in my case, there is no external storage, but only internal one. That internal storage has a Download folder so I thinkI can save my file there. How can I get path for Download folder? by using only "/Download" does not seem to work,

Comment: All devices have "external storage" even though it really is a part of the built-in flash, as the answer that I linked to shows, use:  `Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads)` and your app will need runtime permission to access it...

Comment: Thanks!!!! it worked! I understand now the concept of external storage. I did not even need to set permissions... I saved a video file in Movies folder, then I point to it using Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryMovies setting the source in Plugin.MediaManager and it worked like a charm.