# How to download file save and open from FileSystem.CacheDirectory in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, xamarin.forms, webclient

I want to download PDF or any other type of file from my API by url, then give it a name (like 1234.pfd) and save it to ***FileSystem.CacheDirectory***, and download its using ***DownloadFileAsync***. I tried debug and see, does it have files in it or am I mistaken? When calling to open it as well ***Launcher.OpenAsync*** (for open any file type such as .pdf or .pptx by using its Xamarin.Essential), it goes up to choose what to open with, but when I choose to be my app's pdf viewer, it bounces back to my app itself, won't open the content, or sometimes I get an error unable to identify the file.

[file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eWRN.png),
[path want to open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcQw5.png)

Comment: Make sure that the app get the permission to read/write file to file system . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56875215/in-xamarin-forms-how-can-i-copy-a-file-from-the-isolated-storage-to-the-downloa

Answer (score 0):

At the top you will need

```cs
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
```

And the code itself looks like:

```cs
string localFileName = "myfile.jpg"
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string localFileNamePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, localFileName);
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://somewebsite.com/somefile.jpg"), localFileNamePath);
FileBase fileBase = new ReadOnlyFile(localFileNamePath);
fileBase.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
fileBase.FileName = localFileNamePath;
OpenFileRequest openFileRequest = new OpenFileRequest("bubu", fileBase);
await Launcher.OpenAsync(openFileRequest);
```

This was my code to donwload a jpg. You will want to use application/pdf